# JavaFX hide Node after some duration

Tags: java, javafx

A `Stage` exist which contains some simple nodes like a `Circle`(RIGHT) and a `Rectangle`(LEFT) in a `BordePane` Layout.

1. What I want is if the mouse has not been moved for 1 second (in the window) the circle to disappear.
2. If the elememt has not entered `Rectangle` during the last 1 second the rectangle to disappear.

I am thinking of using a `Thread` but it doesn't seem right.

Is there any `JavaFX` packages to do this?Some code would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a couple of `PauseTransition`s:

```
PauseTransition hideCircle = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
PauseTransition hideRectangle = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));

// restart hideCircle if mouse moves in window:
scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> hideCircle.playFromStart());

// restart hideRectangle if mouse enters rectangle:
rectangle.setOnMouseEntered(e -> hideRectangle.playFromStart());

// hide circle if pause gets to end:
hideCircle.setOnFinished(e -> circle.setVisible(false));

// hide rectangle if pause gets to end:
hideRectangle.setOnFinished(e -> rectangle.setVisible(false));

// start "timers":
hideCircle.play();
hideRectangle.play();
```

You might prefer to remove the shapes from their parent instead of setting `visible` to false, depending on exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `javafx.concurrent.Task<V>` (doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) to implement a background listener that would react to your changes, once you want to do something with the GUI elements do it in `Platform.runLater()`

Comment: Can you give me an idea on how to do the above asked 1and 2 ?I mean some code or with words...